# Is Bioshock 2 harder to understand while playing if the player never played Bioshock 1?

Tags: bioshock-2

I own Bioshock 2, and I'd like to give it a try, but I do not own Bioshock 1 and know nothing about it.

Will my ignorance of the first game hinder my ability to understand whats going on in the second?

Edit-Afterthought:

Please do your best to keep any answers **spoiler-free** if possible.

Comment: Bioshock 2 is a good game, and I'mma let you finish it, but Bioshock 1 is one of the best videogames of **all time**.

Comment: @agent86 what do you mean by let me finish it? how would you stop me? IS THAT YOU OUTSIDE MY WINDOW!?!?! (I haven't even started it actually, wanted to ask this question before I did and became dissapointed)

Comment: @agent86 Where is Kanye when ya need him?

Comment: The better question is "Is there any good reason to play BS2 before BS1?" and the answer is "No, not even if your children are starving and you have to have them steal their classmates' lunch money so you can afford to buy the game."

Comment: Yeah I would definitely play BS1 before BS2, at the very least because BS1 was a pretty good game, while BS2 was, IMHO, boring.  The next one (BS-Infinite) looks amazing, though :D

Comment: BS2 also has heavy spoilers for BS1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I'd say from a story perspective, you really should play BioShock 1 first.  There are several recurring themes between the two games, and much of the exposition and explanation is contained in the first game.

You won't just miss secondary elements and little bits of plot and sidequest significance - you'll be missing out on a large chunk of the experience.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that would be the case and didn't want to encounter the issue after I got 'into' the game.

Comment: @Ender, yeah, this is watching the "Empire Strikes Back" without first seeing "Star Wars."  You'd be like "Why is that ghost talking to that creepy looking green thing?"